# Using Quill in a form and transfering data to a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax, quill

I have a very simple form that has a field for a title and uses quill to enter a discussion. I have tried everything I can think of, but still cannot populate a mysql database with the information. I think I'm getting close, but am not quite there yet.  I think the problem lies in my use of json and ajax.

Here is my html file that creates the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Discussions</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.2.2/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href = "../css/discussionsEditor.css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.2.2/quill.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="form-container" class="container">
        <form id="discussionForm" method = "post" action ="discussionsEditor.php" role="form">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" name="title" type="text" placeholder="Title">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <input name="discussionContent" type="hidden">
                <div id="editor-container">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

        <script>
            var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
                modules: {
                toolbar: [
                ['bold', 'italic'],
                ['link', 'blockquote', 'code-block', 'image'],
                [{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }]
                ]
                },
                placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
                theme: 'snow' 
                });
        </script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/discussionsEditor.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my javascript file where I try to use json and ajax to transfer the data.

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');
form.onsubmit = function() {
  // Populate hidden form on submit
    var discussionContent = document.querySelector('input[name=discussionContent]');
    discussionContent.value = JSON.stringify(quill.getContents());

    var url ="discussionsEditor.php";
    var data = stringify(quill.getContents());
    alert( "the data is " + data);
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : url,
        data : discussionContent,

        success: function ()
        {
            alert("Successfully sent to database");
        },
        error: function()
        {
        alert("Could not send to database");
        }       
    });
    return false;
};
```

and finally here is my php file

```
<?php
            try
            {
                $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=mydb', "user", "password");
                $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
            }
            catch (PDOException $e)
            {
                $output = 'Unable to connect to the database server:' . $e->getMessage();
                include '../output.html.php';
                exit();
            }

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    echo "<br />";
    echo "the title is " . $title;
            $discussionContent = $_POST['discussionContent'];
    echo "<br />";
    echo "the discussion content is ". $discussionContent;


    $sql = 'INSERT INTO Discussions(Title, DiscussionContent)
    Values(:Title, :DiscussionContent)';
    $statement = $pdo -> prepare($sql);
    $statement -> execute(array(':Title' => $title, ':DiscussionContent' => $discussionContent));

?>
```

If I put 'Denise' in the title field and 'cute' in the quill discussion field, the echo statements in the php file give this result:

the title is Denise

the discussion content is {"ops":[{"insert":"Cute\n"}]}

Nothing is stored in the database.

I would appreciate and help or comments.  Thanks

Comment: Any db errors being thrown?

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: if this has been store to database, how to display it as html?

Answer (score 5):

Use getText() method if you simply need a Text value from your quill editor like below:

```
var quillText = quill.getText();
```

If you are planning to store HTML data in DB use

```
var quillHtml = quill.root.innerHTML.trim();
```

pass the value to your ajax data like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : url,
    data: {editorContent : quillText },
    success: function (data,status, xhr)
    {
      if(xhr.status == 200) {
        alert("Successfully sent to database");
      }
    },error: function() {
       alert("Could not send to database");
    }       
});
```

Reason to post as "editorContent" is that you can get the posted values simply by

```
$_POST['editorContent']
```

in your PHP script.

After further sanitization, insert the data to DB(either HTML or TEXT).
Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following.It may help to resolve the issue:

## comment is editor id.

var quill = new Quill('#comment');
var cc =  quill.container.firstChild.innerHTML;

Now cc will hold the data of your div element.That can be inserted into DB.It is just example.You can use if it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Quill.js is amazing rich text editor but there is very low amount of Youtube videos and google articles about it, other than that their documentation is hard to understand. So new users may have trouble using it.

Lets come to your code...

You need to remove all attributes from form tag except "id".

Your old:

```
<form id="discussionForm" method = "post" action ="discussionsEditor.php" role="form">
```

I suggest:

```
<form id="discussionForm" class="You Can Use Class">
```

Great, You have done everything fine in JS but you have passed the object wrongly while posting the data. (***I also make some new changes***)

**JavaScript:-**

Wait... I hope you haven't forgotten to use this code block in your JS.

```
var quill = new Quill('#service_details_editor', {
    modules: {
        toolbar: toolbarOptions
    },
    theme: 'snow'
});

//var form = document.querySelector('form');
$("#discussionForm").on('submit', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

  // Populate hidden form on submit
    var discussionContent = document.querySelector('input[name=discussionContent]');
    discussionContent.value = JSON.stringify(quill.getContents());

    var url ="discussionsEditor.php";
   var form = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : url,
        data : form,
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,

        success: function (response) //Response which is come from "discussionsEditor.php" if Query run successfully. 
        {
            alert("Successfully sent to database");
        },
        error: function(response)
        {
        alert("Could not send to database");
        }       
    });
    return false;
});
```

**PHP:-**

Your PHP may working well no doubt but I usually write PHP like this.

```
   //Connection Block Start
    <?php
    
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password = '';
    $db_name = "Your DB Name";
    
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db_name);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Failed to connect with MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    //Connection Block END



if (isset($_POST['title'])) {

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $DiscussionContent = $_POST['DiscussionContent'];
  
 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Discussions(title,DiscussionContent) VALUES ('$title','$DiscussionContent')";

        if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
            echo 1;
        } else {
            echo 0;
        }
        }


    die();
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy way:

```
<form method="post" id="identifier">

  <div id="quillArea"></div>

  <textarea name="text" style="display:none" id="hiddenArea"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />

</form>
```

If you give the form an identifier, then using jQuery you can do the following:

```
var quill = new Quill ({...}) //definition of the quill
$("#identifier").on("submit",function() {
  $("#hiddenArea").val($("#quillArea").html());
})
```

Now once you have the HTML in the textarea simple post it by clicking submit button

If you want to get only the content, you can add .ql-editor to your selector : `$("#hiddenArea").val($("#quillArea .ql-editor").html());`